# How to disable password authentication and root login Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-22.04

Good morning all,

I'm new to the realm of Ubuntu/server management and likely have a dumb question. But i am really struggling to disable root login and password authentication. For context, i have setup public key login via SSH to my ubuntu server on my account running on my raspberry pi, but can't disable root login or password authentication.

I have tried editing the sshd_config file and set PasswordAuthentication to 'no' but that doesn't prevent it. I also don't have an option to disable root login. I have researched and found people refering to 'ChallengeResponseAuthentication' to disbale password authentication but can't find any reference to it.

Could it be because i am not signed in as root and instead and am on a separate user account? And if so, how do i sign in as root? Using the Ubuntu username and blank password just says incorrect password.

Comment: Set both `PasswordAuthentication` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` to no is correct. Did you restart or reload sshd service after you update the configuration in /etc/ssh/sshd_config?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response :) I did restart the sshd service and still cant see either option

Comment: In this case, you may check /var/log/auth.log to see what happens during authentication.  And enable verbose log in client side is also useful: `ssh -vvv root@remote-host`

Comment: Nothing too obvious as to what is going on. It does refer to something called PAM, and the comments for that in the sshd_config do mention challengeresponseauthentication

Comment: Just did another fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS through the Raspberry Pi Imager. Still none of those options (PermitRootLogin & Password Authentication) do not disable in the sshd_config

Answer (score 2):

Check if there are files inside  /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d
, if any config file is present; if `PasswordAuthentication yes` is found you can delete such line. In Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS iso, i found /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/50-cloud-init.conf overides the sshd_config file, which had passwordauthentication enabled.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @sherpaurgen's answer: it's well worth reading the comments in `/etc/sshd_config`, noting that (in Ubuntu) the first line includes files in `/etc/sshd_config.d`, and that the first occurrence of a configuration setting applies (as per the man page, see `man sshd_config`) - so certainly see if there's anything in that directory taking precedence over anything in `/etc/sshd_config`, as well as understanding what the defaults are (in a fresh installation the defaults will typically be shown commented out).

It's also worth noting that you're asking 3 things, so tick each item off as you get them working - remember to reload sshd after any config changes (`systemctl reload sshd.service`):

- Disable password authentication
- Disable root login
- How to sign in as `root`

You and others have already noted the settings for the first 2, I'll suggest `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` instead of its now deprecated alias `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` (don't have both to avoid confusion, as aliases the first occurrence of either will take precedence), so probably these lines,

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin no
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
```

I suggest putting those in a local settings file in `/etc/sshd_config.d` as mentioned above (check the corresponding `include` line appears at the top of `/etc/sshd_config`).

The final one, signing in as `root` is typically achieved by signing in as your normal user id then using `sudo` (`sudo -i`, see man pages with `man sudo`, also the man pages it references in the 'see also' section near the end of the man page). Re. your question *"Could it be because i am not signed in as root and instead and am on a separate user account?"* you can check 'who' you are with the command `whoami` or for more detail `id`

At the risk of stating the obvious, all the `sshd...` settings will affect logins via ssh, they have nothing to do with console logins; I understand your question to relate to ssh so I've not addressed console login. Finally make sure you're working with `sshd_config` and `sshd_config.d` (note the **d**) for the SSH *server* settings (ssh connections to your Raspberry Pi).